# Filter out entries that don't have the latest date within their subcategory

Tags: sql, database, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I'm using Ms access 2010. My data is as follows:

PROJECT (Mostly words), of which there's many:

REQUESTS(Mostly numbers around 1 to 20, not necesarily in sequential order and some registered as "1 and 2" as an example), every requests has many:

NEGOTIATIONS (Dates) or more precisely, "end of negotiation dates" and they aren't in chronological order.

What I need is to have the data in it's original order, except for entries that AREN'T the latest date within it's negotiation.

What I have:

```
id | PROJECT NAME| REQUEST| DATE  
1 ----- bla ------- 3 ----- 1-2-17  
2 ----- bla ------- 3 ----- 4-2-17  
3 ----- bla ------- 3 ----- 2-2-17  
4 ----- bla ------- 5 ----- 4-2-17  
5 ----- bla ------- 5 ----- 6-2-17  
6 ----- ble ------- 1 ----- 6-2-17 
7 ----- ble ------- 1 ----- 9-2-17  
8 ----- ble ------- 3 ----- 5-3-17 
9 ----- ble ------- 3 ----- 6-3-17  
10 ---- ble ------- 3 ----- 5-3-17
```

What I need:

```
id | PROJECT NAME| REQUEST| DATE 
2 ----- bla -------- 3 ---- 4-2-17  
5 ----- bla -------- 5 ---- 6-2-17  
7 ----- ble -------- 1 ---- 9-2-17  
9 ----- ble -------- 3 ---- 6-3-17
```

I don't know where to start.

Comment: Please provide sample data and expected result.

Comment: Done. I was editing it in, actually.

Comment: Are the `request` always in consecutive values? Is it possible to skip a value, e.g.: `1`,`2`,`4`?

Comment: Yes. in fact, most entries start with numbers other than 1, and values do skip.

Comment: actually I do not understand the expected result at all. What are entries that ARE the lastest date within it's negotiation?

Comment: I'm sorry, that was a very bad example. I don't know what I was thinking, now I corrected it.

Comment: I guess third row should have 9-2-17 right?

Comment: I think it is a gap and island problem. Try to search a little here on SO.

Comment: And shouldn't last row be 6-3-17?

Comment: You are correct. I'm messing this up badly. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @example as table (
    ExampleID int identity(1,1) not null primary key clustered
,   ProjectName nvarchar(3) not null
,   Request int not null
,   Date_ date not null
);

insert into @example (ProjectName, Request, Date_)


select 'bla', 3, eomonth(sysdatetime(), -7) union all
select 'bla', 3, eomonth(sysdatetime(), -3) union all
select 'bla', 3, eomonth(sysdatetime(), -4) union all
select 'bla', 5, eomonth(sysdatetime(), -7) union all
select 'bla', 5, eomonth(sysdatetime(), -6) union all
select 'ble', 1, eomonth(sysdatetime(), -6) union all
select 'ble', 1, eomonth(sysdatetime(), -5) union all
select 'ble', 3, eomonth(sysdatetime(), -2) union all
select 'ble', 3, eomonth(sysdatetime(), -1) union all
select 'ble', 3, eomonth(sysdatetime(), -2);

;with cte as (
    select ProjectName  
         , Request
         , max(date_) over(partition by projectname, request order by projectName, Request ) Date_
      from @example 
            )

select distinct ExampleID
     , a.ProjectName
     , a.Request
     , a.Date_
  from @example a
  join cte b
    on a.Date_ = b.Date_
   and a.ProjectName = b.ProjectName
   and a.Request = b.Request
```

---

### Previous Q&A

There is a fundamental issue with your logic or your data.

in your example:

```
id | PROJECT NAME| REQUEST| DATE  
1 ----- bla ------- 1 ----- 1-2-17  
2 ----- bla ------- 2 ----- 4-2-17  
3 ----- bla ------- 3 ----- 2-2-17
```

the solution would be parsing the ID which makes the assumption that your surrogate key is in chronological order, against the date and excluding where the date is less than the previous date for the prior record based on project name. (chronological order does not imply that it is contiguous)

The logic breaks down when you have something like:

```
id | PROJECT NAME| REQUEST| DATE  
1 ----- bla ------- 1 ----- 1-2-17  
2 ----- bla ------- 2 ----- 4-2-17  
3 ----- bla ------- 3 ----- 2-2-17
4 ----- bla ------- 6 ----- 6-2-17
```

Now you should expect something like:

```
id | PROJECT NAME| REQUEST| DATE 
4 ----- bla -------- 6 ---- 6-2-17
```

Would this be an acceptable result set?

Comment: The result should actually be entries 1, 2, 3 and 4. Since they are all from different requests.

Comment: In case you didn't know, I recently corrected the examples, which were very bad.

Comment: So then project doesn't really matter as the request will show the grouping

Comment: OP tagged MS Access not SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

Consider joining unit level query with an aggregate query, returning rows equal to *MaxDate*:

```
SELECT n.ID, p.[PROJECT NAME], r.[REQUEST], n.[DATE]
FROM ((PROJECTS p
INNER JOIN REQUESTS r ON p.ProjectID = r.ProjectID)
INNER JOIN NEGOTIATIONS n ON r.RequestID = n.RequestID)

INNER JOIN
   (SELECT p.[PROJECT NAME], r.[REQUEST], MAX(n.[DATE]) AS MAX_DATE
    FROM ((PROJECTS p
    INNER JOIN REQUESTS r ON p.ProjectID = r.ProjectID)
    INNER JOIN NEGOTIATIONS n ON r.RequestID = n.RequestID)
    GROUP BY p.[PROJECT NAME], r.[REQUEST]
   ) AA aggdf

ON p.[PROJECT NAME] = aggdf.[PROJECT NAME]
AND r.[REQUEST] = aggdf.[REQUEST]
AND n.[DATE] = aggdf.MAX_DATE

ORDER BY n.ID, p.[PROJECT NAME], r.[REQUEST], n.[DATE]
```

Comment: OP, what error or undesired result did you encounter with this solution?